# SDL Can't load OpenGL Context over 2.1 Mac OSX Yosemite

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, osx-yosemite, sdl-2

I am running Mac OSX Yosemite Version 10.10 and the latest version of SDL (2.0.3).

I am trying to use at least OpenGL version 3+. Without doing anything, my OpenGL version returns `2.1 INTEL-10.0.86`.

The OpenGL commands work, but this is obviously not the version I need.

So, after doing some research I found the way to change the version with SDL is through the `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GLattr attr, int value)` function after you initialize SDL but before you define the context. So here is my code:

```
if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to initialize SDL. Error (SDL): %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1); //I read somewhere that this may help

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, (SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN));

if (!window)
{
    printf("Failed to create the window. Error (SDL): %s.\n", SDL_GetError());
    return false;
}

context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
```

Using this code, the OpenGL version reports `4.1 INTEL-10.0.86`. This would work well but none of my OpenGL calls work anymore so I checked for an OpenGL error after a function is called and it returns `1282`.

The strange thing is that when I change the code to this

```
...
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1); //I read somewhere that this may help
...
```

It gives the same output `4.1 INTEL-10.0.86` and returns the same OpenGL error (1282) and none of the OpenGL functions work.

And my last attempt failed as well with a different outcome. Here was my code:

```
...
//SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1); //I read somewhere that this may help
...
```

The new OpenGL version returned is `null` but if I change the major_version to 2 and minor_version to 1 it returns to my original version `2.1 INTEL-10.0.86`.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

**--Edit--**

After doing some additional research, if OpenGL returns 1282 after every call the context is not initialized correctly. This leads me to believe that this may be a bug with SDL not correctly creating the context? (I honestly don't know that much so I'm going on a limb). I'll submit a bug to SDL and see if that helps anything.

Comment: Are you sure that your hardware and driver support version 3? The "intel" makes me suspect they don't.

Comment: @molbdnilo Using https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/, it says it supports 4.1. I am running using the HD Graphics 4000. Also, search for Intel HD Graphics 4000 here  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5942.

Comment: Also, a comment would be helpful along with the down vote to understand how to improve my question or what's wrong with it.

Comment: I didn't downvote. There's nothing wrong with your question, in my opinion.

Comment: @molbdnilo It was supposed to be directed at the person who did down vote. I guess the also was a bit misleading, sorry :P.

Comment: "none of my OpenGL calls work anymore"...and which calls might those be, exactly?

Comment: @genpfault Any of them. `glMatrixMode`, `glLoadIdentity`, `glLoadIdentity`, `glBegin` , etc... The only one that seems to not give an error is the glGetString - to print the version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE`

...

> ...none of my OpenGL calls [**glMatrixMode, glLoadIdentity, glLoadIdentity, glBegin**] work anymore...

Those are all deprecated and will not work in a Core context.

If you want to continue using a Core context you'll have to re-write your program to not use deprecated functionality.

Comment: I was unaware those were deprecated. I'll try some OpenGL 4 commands.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. You don't know the trouble I went through to find this even though it was a stupid mistake. Thank you though! :)

Comment: @TrevorPeyton: No problem!  Next time though make sure to post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), the Core context/legacy GL command disconnect would have been identifiable right away.